# How do I delete a sharepoint group that has arabic characters in the title?

Tags: moss, wss, stsadm

I have a sharepoint group that has arabic characters in the title.  The site has been deleted, and I need to remove the group.  When I use the GUI, I get this error message:

> Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator. (12202)

When I use `stsadm -o enumgroups` I get this as the group name:

```
<Name>Blah blah -- ????? ??????? ????????? Members</Name>
```

`stsadm -o deletegroup -name "Blah blah -- ????? ??????? ????????? Members" -url http://myurl.com` returns:

> Group cannot be found.

I know the group ID, any way I can use that in my quest for deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `deletegroup` requires the site URL as well. In this case I think you'll have to use the OM - you can use the `SPGroupCollection.RemoveByID()` method to do so.

Comment: yes, I passed in the URL parameter.  I just didn't type it in the question because I was lazy.

Comment: Fair enough! The other option is to just try copying and pasting the group name from 'People and Groups' into the command window with stsadm, though I doubt the Windows command prompt will accept the characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a console application to explore the group, (see if there is any information within it that you need to keep) and then delete it.

Comment: I can explore the group just fine.  My problem lies in the mechanics of deleting.  Do I need to delete is using the object model?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to, I just know that you can. So that's how I would.